# Syntax error in parameter list

Tags: verilog

i am new to verilog. I have a project consisted of 3 files which i try to compile using the command:

```
iverilog -o ddr3 drac_ddr3.v adapter.v top.v
```

and i get an error msg:

> drac_ddr3.v:335: syntax error
>       drac_ddr3.v:335: error: syntax error in parameter list.
>       drac_ddr3.v:336: syntax error
>       drac_ddr3.v:336: error: syntax error in parameter list.

**Copy of lines 335-336:**

```
333:`ifdef XILINX_ISIM
334:`else  
335:    parameter integer bank_a[15:0] = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
336:    parameter integer bank_ba[2:0] = {0, 1, 1};
337:`endif
```

it doesn't seem to have any syntax errors. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Parameters are usually for constants. Do you want constants here, or module inputs?

Comment: Did you grab the code from the net or write it yourself? You may have to throw a verilog version switch...

Comment: I got the code from: http://opencores.org/project,ddr3_sdram  it is a university project. I have to compile it first and then run simulations, and improve some functions. Like making it more energy sufficient or add another function. or making it faster.

Comment: @ Dimitrios, If you are new, please ask question in a logical way. you should show the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define parameters as follow:

```
parameter [15:0] bank_a= 16'b0010010000000111;
parameter [2:0]  bank_ba = 3'b011;
```

The size of an `integer` variable is always 32 bits. What you're trying to do is to define "non-integer" parameters, which are 16 and 3 bits wide.

Comment: Well, i tried this and i get the following error: drac_ddr3.v:335: warning: extra digits given for sized binary constant.